# I Can't install Scikit-learn for python 3.7

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Admittedly I am relatively new to python. I want to install scikit-learn into Python 3.7. I understand that scikit-learn requires Numpy and Scipy. When trying to  install Scikit-learn using pip I get the wall of text in this [Document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/16VuE0qGYnhHbHIUoMslky3ybi9rj8Uu6J7IDmNcM4jE/edit?usp=sharing). The following are the versions for Numpy and Scipy:

Numpy version: 1.14.5

Scipy version: 1.1.0

Again this is on Python version 3.7.0

Comment: can you write the specific command you use? it is useful to see what flags you are (or aren't) using

Comment: python 3.7 came out 2 weeks ago. I am certainly usually one to strive to use the most up-to-date software for everything, but maybe go back to 3.6.4 for a bit until 3.7 has been around for a bit and everyone's caught up with the changes.

Comment: Also for complicated extension modules like numpy and scipy, the by far easiest way to install them is to grab a pre-compiled version packaged with something like [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/).

Comment: [This](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.6_win-64) list shows the packages available and which ones are installed by default if you install anaconda with python 3.6 for windows 64 bit. Both Scikit-image and Scikit-learn are installed by default.

Comment: Yeah I just installed 3.7.0 with [Pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) (my favorite way to deal with multiple local Python versions) and it couldn't build scikit-learn. Here's [Scikit-learn's GitHub issue tracking 3.7 compatibility](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/11320). Use 3.6 for now.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like scikit-learn is now 3.7-compatible: [#11320](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/11320) tracking the issue is now closed.

Answer (score 0):

My python version is 3.7.4, I have also struggled to install scikit-learn. But it worked for me by installing

```
pip install sklearn
```

when we install this automatically

joblib-0.14.1,
scikit-learn-0.22.1, and
sklearn-0.0

will be installed....!

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

This works for me.