# Using pip3 to install scikit-learn

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, pip

I am beginning to use python3 and I am trying to install packages using pip3. Specifically, I am trying to install scikit-learn and having issues. It allows me to install using pip:

```
pip install scikit-learn
```

but when using:

```
pip3 install scikit-learn
```

I get this error:

```
Command "/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/k2/3zzndk0d3bv1pc8krbkq19_00000gn/T/pip-install-7rawonsv/scikit-learn/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/k2/3zzndk0d3bv1pc8krbkq19_00000gn/T/pip-record-fyi90hl7/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/k2/3zzndk0d3bv1pc8krbkq19_00000gn/T/pip-install-7rawonsv/scikit-learn/
```

Comment: try with sudo it seems like you don't have permission for directory, /private/var/folders/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be still some issues with using `pip` for installing scikit-learn in Python **3.7**, which you seem to be using; see:

- [`pip install` fails (compile error) with Python 3.7rc1](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/11320) issue at Github
- [I Can't install Scikit-learn for python 3.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51314845/i-cant-install-scikit-learn-for-python-3-7) thread here at SO

The recommended solution, at least for the time being, is to revert to an older version of Python (e.g. 3.6).

Answer (score 0):

I notice you are using python 3.7 and as its very new and there are many packages which are still not compatible with it. You can probably try downloading the package's wheel file and manually install it. I think sklearn 0.20dev version has wheels for py3.7.

Refer this link: http://scikit-learn.org/dev/developers/advanced_installation.html#installing-build-dependencies

And as @desertnaut suggested, its better to just revert back to an older python version (3.5 or 3.6 maybe).